# href not loading link every time part of the li is clicked. Using javascript to make the whole li clickable

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists

http://hemakessites.com

I'd like to click the About button to go to the About page. I'm using Javascript and JQuery to handle the behavior (make the whole li clickable). For some reason, clicking about in different areas of the li doesn't always load the page.

I'm open to not using jQuery if there's a better solution.

The "contact information" and "hobby projects" li don't have an href, so the links don't work. If you go to the About page, the menu works based on CSS without the javascript trying to make the whole li clickable. So there is no javascript on the about.html page, and you can see the menu problem without any javascript.

Thanks for your help!

```
index.html
    <div class="navcontainer">
    <ul><li>Link Title</
    li><li>Second_Link Title</ <!-- fixes extra space with </li><li> -->
    li></ul>
    </div>


style.css
    #nav li
      {
      display: inline-block;
      List-Style-Type: None;
      float:left;
      text-align:Center;
      width: 153px;
      height:46px;  
      font-size: 80%;
      border-Bottom: 1px solid #666666;
      }

    #nav li #about    
      {
      z-index: 10000;
      position: relative;
      top: 18px;
      text-decoration: underline;
      -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      }
```

Comment: please provide the relevant markup / code in your question, so it can help others in the future.

Comment: Good suggestion, Hamish. Trimming the code now.

Comment: I think jQuery in this instance is overkill.  The simpler the better.  K.I.S.S.  There are plenty of tutorials online showing how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

just add the following in your CSS:

```
#nav li.about a{
z-index:10000; }
```

and it will work

Comment: It's really exciting to see someone answer my question! I tried adding


    #nav li.about a{
    z-index:10000; }

to my style.css and had no luck. Clicking the top section of the about button (while hovering) still doesn't execute the link. Thanks for your suggestion, Fabio!

Comment: Which browser are you using? just in case, try adding a position:relative to the a element and see if it solves it, but at least in FF it works fine for me

Comment: Hmm... I'll try it in Firefox. I'm using Google Chrome and adding z-index to other elements such as #nav li #about #nav li.about:hover or #nav li:hover #about isn't fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not the javascript, but the CSS.  You have a hover attribute that enlarges the `<li>`.  When you click, the active attribute causes it to shrink, making the element smaller than it previously was.  If you click in the upper corners of the enlarged element, it won't load because the element is now below the clickable area.  If you click in the middle towards the bottom, it will.

Ultimately, for something like this, you might be better off using jQuery UI to manage your tabs or use Twitter Bootstrap.  Out of the box it works, and you don't have to worry about CSS issues, plus they already look nice so no extra styling.

If you want to stick with you already have going, you may just want to ditch the fancy CSS.  Get rid of the :active class and it should work okay I think.

Comment: You're right. The only way to keep the effect is to change the javascript to execute the href on mousedown instead of on click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have right now is that the `li` is bigger then the `a`. Clicking on the `l`i, but outside the `a` will not make the link work, as you already found out.

In stead of applying all your styles and effects to the `li` element, you should apply them to the `a` element directly and set it to display as a block. This way the `li` will take the same size as the `a`, and whereever you click on the hovered item, your href will work just fine. Bigger links is always a good idea, definitly with the amount of tablets and other toutchscreen devices rizing every day.

Note that it will not be a straight copy / paste of your code, especially when it comes to floats and positioning, but it should not be to hard to achieve what you are after by applying the styles directly to the `a` element. If you have difficulty converting your code, feel free to set up a working example on jsfiddle and we will be happy to help out where possible.

This solution does not require any js what so ever. Using js for your main navigation is always a bad idea, as it will make it hard, if not impossible, to navigate your site for people with js disabled. Not exactly what i would call gracefull degrading...